# How to exclude unicode characters in email address?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

How to exclude the email address which has  unicode characters using regular expression?
I have an email address **job.rajü@example.de** 
I need to validate the email address and should accept only those email's which doesn't have unicode characters using regular expression.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript

Comment: Why wouldn't you validate a valid email address? Anyway, note that there is no real way to **validate** an email address. The user can write a syntactically correct address that does not exist or a dummy email address (e.g. mailinator) which is valid and exists but is not his real address.

Comment: Every character in **job.rajü@example.de** is a Unicode character.  Do you mean that you want to exclude non-ASCII characters?

Comment: Just use [A-Za-z] wherever you want to match a letter. Simple as that.

Comment: What i am looking for is that.. suppose i have 10 email address and out of that two are there which contains the character ü, i need to show an error message for these two email address that you cannot have multi byte characters in the email address.

Comment: \A(\w|['])+([-+.](\w|['])+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*
this is my current regular expression.

Comment: @FailedDev: `[A-Za-z]` excludes digits, which are perfectly valid in e-mail addresses.

Comment: @KeithThompson As I said, *put this wherever you want to match letter*. Last time I checked letter != digit.

Comment: @FailedDev: Ok -- but the OP didn't mention letters.  I'm afraid I don't see the relevance of your comment.

Comment: @KeithThompson I c what you mean. So [A-Za-z0-9] is what I meant I guess.

Comment: @nico, it sounds like you're confusing validation and verification. Validation would be checking to see whether the address in syntactically correct; whether an email address is 'real' or is nonexistant/a dummy is down to verification.

Comment: Voting to close as dupe.  You should be validating e-mail addresses the "right" way.  It is very tricky, so don't re-invent the wheel.  Just use an existing JavaScript solution *and* validate it server-side with a real e-mail address validator.  It is darn near impossible to fully validate all possible valid e-mail addresses using regex alone - they are much too complicated.

Comment: [This regex is fully compliant](http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html).  But I wouldn't trust it to work.  It is just the wrong language for the job.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses

Comment: @Jordan Wallwork: if you wish, I include existence of email address in the "validation" process. A matter of semantics.

Comment: @FailedDev: `[A-Za-z0-9]` still excludes a number of characters that are perfectly valid in e-mail addresses.  (It would reject mine, for example.)  I think the syntax of valid e-mail addresses is more complex than you think it is; I'm fairly sure it's more complex than *I* think it is.  8-)}

Comment: I know that is more complex.. And as I said for nth time this should only be used where a ASCII "letter/digit" is involved.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to accept any valid email address, I'd suggest taking a look at "[Comparing E-mail Address Validating Regular Expressions](http://fightingforalostcause.net/misc/2006/compare-email-regex.php)."  Here's the best email regex they have for matching all valid email addresses.

For JavaScript:

```
/^[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+(\.[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+)*@([a-z0-9_][-a-z0-9_]*(\.[-a-z0-9_]+)*\.(aero|arpa|biz|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|mil|museum|name|net|org|pro|travel|mobi|[a-z][a-z])|([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}))(:[0-9]{1,5})?$/i
```

I've created an example at JSBin of this in action in JavaScript:

- http://jsbin.com/owedez/2/

Comment: So you just copy a regex from a site, which you don't even know what it does and paste it here? I think If I flip a coin I will have more chances..

Comment: I've used these regex before.  If you want full details about how they work, read the site.  I pasted it here for easier access and in case the site ever goes offline.

Comment: I've added a JSBin example and tested to verify that the JavaScript regex does not accept the unicode characters I tested.

Comment: I was writing a response, but this one passed on every case! +1